# How to get full card number in human readable formate using card.io android SDK?

Tags: android, scanning, card.io

I have used card.io to scan my credit card in my android application. I got the scanned number but it shows •••• •••• •••• 2157.

Now I need to exact card number so that I can pass that number on payment detail form.

```
CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);
strCardNumber = scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this line

```
scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber()
```

with

```
scanResult.getFormattedCardNumber()
```

and you will get the readable card number.